# Button to take to a specific slider depending on actual template

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, ionic-framework

I have a "Help" button that brings up a modal window with a slider. What i'm trying to do is to get the "Help" button take you to a specific slide depending on what page you are so if you are in the "login" template the help will take you to the "login" slide inside the help slider and so on.

This is my button:

```
<div ng-controller="ToggleCtrl">  
          <button class="cabecera__link-ayuda" ng-click="modal.show()"><i class="ion-help-circled"></i></button>
        </div>
```

This is my slider:

```
<script id="ayuda.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-modal-view class="modal-ayuda">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header">
      <h1 class="title">Ayuda</h1>
      <button class="button button-clear button-primary" ng-click="modal.hide()"><i class="ion-close"></i></button>
    </ion-header-bar>  
    <ion-view title="Ayuda"> 
      <ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged(index)">
        <ion-slide>
          <ion-content>
            <h1 class="texto-azul centrado">APP BSRenting</h1>
            <h2>Bienvenido</h2>
            <p>Esta Aplicación permite registrar las incidencias asociadas al servicio de renting de vehículos.</p>
            <p>La aplicación que se plantea es una app in-house que facilite la comunicación entre los usuarios de BSRenting y el Contact Center, para la gestión de los partes de accidentes, averías, mantenimiento y robo. El proyecto se incluye en la iniciativa de creación de la app, la Web y la base de datos para gestionar la información, esta propuesta se centra únicamente en la App para dispositivos móviles, los servicios para almacenamiento y consulta de la información y la base de datos para almacenarla.</p>
          </ion-content>  
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
          <ion-content>
            <h1 class="texto-azul centrado">APP BSRenting: Login</h1>
            <div class="centrado">
              <img src="img/screen-login.jpg"/>
            </div>  
            <p>Al iniciar la aplicación el usuario verá su pantalla la pantalla de login, dicha pantalla de solicitaría matrícula y password. Además hay un botón de registrarse.</p>
          </ion-content>  
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
          <ion-content>
            <h1 class="texto-azul centrado">APP BSRenting: Registro</h1>
            <div class="centrado">
              <img src="img/screen-registro.jpg" />
            </div>  
            <p>En el apartado registrarse, el usuario introducirá DNI, Matrícula, email, teléfono y password. Una vez se seleccione registrarse, se realizaran una serie de validaciones en el servidor y de estar todo correcto, se le enviará un correo electrónico con los datos para finalizar su registro.</p>
          </ion-content>  
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
          <ion-content>
            <h1 class="texto-azul centrado">APP BSRenting: Menu</h1>
            <div class="centrado">
              <img src="img/screen-menu.jpg" />
            </div>  
            <p>Una vez entremos en la aplicación se nos deberá mostrar una página donde podremos ver las diferentes opciones de las cuales dispone la aplicación.</p>
          </ion-content>  
        </ion-slide>
      </ion-slide-box> 
    </ion-view>   
  </ion-modal-view>
</script>
```

And this is the app.js:

```
  .controller('ToggleCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal) {
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('ayuda.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
}).then(function (modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
});
})
```

Comment: Is the question about how to switch to a particular slide with Ionix or how to get the current page to Ionic?

Comment: I need to create a button that will take me to a particular slide depending on what's the actual page (the slide will appear as a modal window), so i guess i need to know how to get the current page in order to go to an specific slide. Thanks @TheRodeo